# Date formatting isn't working from the json response

Tags: javascript, json, momentjs

I have the following JSON response and I am trying to format the date.

```
{
    "webservice_status": {
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "message": ""
    },
    "informationList": [{
        "TestNumber": "12",
        "Color": "RED",
        "dateOfPaint": "10242016",
        "location": "Wall"
    }, {
        "TestNumber": "13",
        "Color": "BLUE",
        "dateOfPaint": "10232016",
        "location": "Floor"
    }, {
        "TestNumber": "14",
        "Color": "GREEN",
        "dateOfPaint": "1052016",
        "location": "Wall"
    }, {
        "TestNumber": "15",
        "Color": "BLACK",
        "dateOfPaint": "10232016",
        "location": "Wall"
    }]
}
```

When  I tried to do the moment test as follows, I got `Invalid Date` in the below console log:

```
this.processJSON = function (data_, textStatus_, jqXHR_){
    var dateMoment = data_.informationList[0].dateOfPaint;
    console.log("The date we are testing:" + dateMoment);
    console.log(moment(dateMoment).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
}
```

Instead of using moment here, is it possible to just add slashes in between `10242016` so that it looks something like this `10/24/2016` because moment doesn't seem to be working above. But the problem is that some dates that are getting returned in the JSON response contains slashes and are in correct format. So I would have to check for that as well before applying slashes.

Comment: You can check if the date string contains `/`... If it does not, you add them...

Comment: I am wondering why the person who answered just now suddenly deleted his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) method accepts strings that match ISO 8601 and RFC 2822 format:

> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string matches known [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats, we then check if the string matches the [RFC 2822 Date time](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3) format before dropping to the fall back of `new Date(string)` if a known format is not found.

Since your input is not in a recognized format, you should pass the format parameter to moment parser ([`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)).

> If you don't know the exact format of an input string, but know it could be one of many, you can use an array of formats.

so since your data could also contain `/`, you can use [`moment(String, String[])`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/) passing `['MMDDYYYY', 'MM/DD/YYYY']` as second parameter.

The you can show the value of the moment object using [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) method. `format()` will print `Invalid Date` for invalid inputs like `1052016` (October has 31 days, there is no 52nd of October). You can use [`isValid()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/) to know if a moment object represent a valid date/time.

Here a live example:

```js
var data_ = {
    "webservice_status": {
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "message": ""
    },
    "informationList": [{
        "TestNumber": "12",
        "Color": "RED",
        "dateOfPaint": "10242016",
        "location": "Wall"
    }, {
        "TestNumber": "13",
        "Color": "BLUE",
        "dateOfPaint": "10232016",
        "location": "Floor"
    }, {
        "TestNumber": "14",
        "Color": "GREEN",
        "dateOfPaint": "1052016",
        "location": "Wall"
    }, {
        "TestNumber": "15",
        "Color": "BLACK",
        "dateOfPaint": "10232016",
        "location": "Wall"
    }]
}

var processJSON = function (data_,textStatus_,jqXHR_){
  for(var i=0; i<data_.informationList.length; i++){
    var dateMoment =  data_.informationList[i].dateOfPaint;
    console.log("The date we are testing:"+dateMoment);
    console.log(moment(dateMoment, ['MMDDYYYY', 'MM/DD/YYYY']).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
  }
}

processJSON(data_);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to turn the string `"10242016"` into a `date` representation separated with slaches like `"10/24/2016"`, you can use `.replace()` with a regex using matches like this:

```
var dateMoment = data_.informationList[0].dateOfPaint.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})$/, "$1"+"/"+"$2"+"/"+"$3");
```

**Demo:**

```js
var dateOfPaint =  "10242016";

var dateMoment  = dateOfPaint.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})$/, "$1"+"/"+"$2"+"/"+"$3");
console.log(dateMoment);
```